# How to connect to a mongodb replica set hosted locally in docker from the host machine

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, replicaset

I want to create a local MongoDB replica set in docker so I can locally debug a program requiring mongo sessions/transactions. I have the following compose file to spin up the 3 required nodes. I also have a script that calls `rs.initialize` which is also below.

The servers initialize fine, but my connection using `mongosh mongodb://localhost:27001,localhost:27002,localhost:27003/test?replicaSet=devReplicaSet` fails.

Now the issue is that the hostnames and ports that the *containers* use to connect to each other are different than what the host machine uses to connect to them. So my seed connection works initially with the localhost hostname, then the replicaset connection protocol tries tells the client to connect to something like `mongo1:27017` (as it is seen by the containers). However my host machine doesn't know how to resolve `mongo1:27017`, it knows it as  `localhost:27001` and the connection fails.

So how do I get the containers to forward me to this alternative address OR how do I give them all hostnames and ports they all understand no matter if it's from the host or container?

docker-compose.rs.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: 'mongo1'
    container_name: 'mongo1'
    image: mongo:5
    networks:
      - mongoCluster
    ports:
      - 27001:27017
    expose:
      - 27001
    entrypoint: mongod --replSet devReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,mongo1
  mongo2:
    hostname: 'mongo2'
    container_name: 'mongo2'
    image: mongo:5
    networks:
      - mongoCluster
    ports:
      - 27002:27017
    expose:
      - 27001
    entrypoint: mongod --replSet devReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,mongo2
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
  mongo3:
    hostname: 'mongo3'
    container_name: 'mongo3'
    image: mongo:5
    networks:
      - mongoCluster
    ports:
      - 27003:27017
    expose:
      - 27001
    entrypoint: mongod --replSet devReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,mongo3
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
networks:
  mongoCluster:
```

The powershell script with rs.initialize

```
# Run docker compose up with docker-compose.repl.yml file
docker-compose -f docker-compose.repl.yml up -d

# Wait for 5 seconds
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# Run docker exec -it mongo1 mongosh
docker exec -it mongo1 mongosh --eval "rs.initiate({ `
    _id: 'devReplicaSet', `
    members: [ `
      {_id: 0, host: 'mongo1:27017'}, `
      {_id: 1, host: 'mongo2:27017'}, `
      {_id: 2, host: 'mongo3:27017'} `
    ] `
   })"
```

Comment: Depending on the nature of the issue that you are trying to debug, you may not need three nodes. It's valid to configure a replica set that only has a single member which will support using transactions

Comment: Hmmm I didn't realize that, but still seems like the same problem, follows the same protocol. Seed connects, gets redirected to mongo1:27017 (or no `initiate()` config makes it go to 127.0.0.1:27017. I could probably make expose it on that port but then it could be competing with other dev environments on the same machine. I'd like it to just work on a non-standard port if it's possible.

Comment: Okay, actually I didn't realize I can connect normally (without any replicaset arg and alt seeds) to a single node replicaset and it still supports transactions. So I can at least do that. I'm still interested if there is an answer to the above question, but this does get me to where I want with this particular dev scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string `mongodb://localhost:27001,localhost:27002,localhost:27003/test?replicaSet=devReplicaSet` should agree with the replicaset config

```
members: [ 
  {_id: 0, host: 'mongo1:27017'}, 
  {_id: 1, host: 'mongo2:27017'}, 
  {_id: 2, host: 'mongo3:27017'} 
]
```

the former uses host system domains, the latter uses docker-compose domains.

Comment: Thanks, but I already stated this in my question. You have not posted a solution. This should be a comment. The question is HOW to make them agree. The members can't all be the same host and port, and the host system doesn't know what mongo1,mongo2, and mongo3 are.

Comment: sorry, it must be my English. By "should agree" I mean they should be the same. Any method will do. E.g. you can change network type to `host` and run mongo on different ports like you would do without docker, or keep the bridge, but initiate rs with host domain name and mapped ports so that traffic leaves the virtual network and goes through the host.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, solved by below:
use `extra_hosts` instend of `network_mode: host`
env: Macos

```
services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    hostname: mongo1
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - "mongo1_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo1_config:/data/configdb"
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017"]
```

connecttion: `mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/db?replicaSet=rs0&retryWrites=true&w=majority`